# gadgets.window.adjustHeight() calculates height of the gadget incorrectly

Tags: opensocial

I am writing an opensocial gadget. My structure is something like this:

```
<div style="height:200px;overflow:auto;">
    <div id="dComment">Comments are loaded here.</div>
</div>
```

I update the content of the "dComment" every second, and its content gets some scrolling. 
In my gadget I have specified `<Require feature="dynamic-height"/>` 
When I use `gadgets.windows.adjustHeight()` it calculates the height of the content regardless that I have made some part of it hidden through adjusting a height for my outer div. As a result I see a huge white space below my content !!!
I know that I can specify height for adjustHeight function. But then it means that on every update I have to calculate the height of the gadget myself, and I don't want to do it (if possible).

Can someone explain to me why it happens and how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `visibility:hidden` use `display:none`